# ckecked element number in :nth-child css rule

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got some radiobuttons on my page and some sections.

```
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="responsive-tabs" class="responsive-select" checked>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="responsive-tabs" class="responsive-select">

<section id="content1">
some content
</section>

<section id="content2" >
some content
</section>
```

I need n'th section to bee seen when n-th radiobutton selected.
Of course, it's easy to achieve by using jquery, but i would like to do this by css only, so please help me. Now i do it like this

```
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}
```

but i want this css rule to be more flexible and independable from elements count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect with the `:target` pseudoclass (using links instead of radio input) on modern browsers

> **Example** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yHEIs

**Markup**

```
<a href="#content1">Tab1</a>
<a href="#content2">Tab2</a>
<a href="#content3">Tab3</a>

<section id="content1">
  some content 1
</section>

<section id="content2" >
  some content 2
</section>

<section id="content3" >
  some content 3
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section { display: none }
section:target { display: block; }
```

---

From a simple cross-browsing perspective, the `:target` pseudoclass has the same support of the `:checked` pseudoclass (both are supported since IE9) but from a functional point of view a tab panel realized with anchors works better even when CSS is not applied on the page (because the page will simply scroll to the section) and you may also have permalinks to every single tab (just add the hash fragment to the url)

Further information on `:target`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) and [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/)

Comment: perfect, but how to make first to be selected bu default?

Comment: you may call the page with the hash `#section1`