# :target pseudoclass follow-up

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have a follow up for the question answered on this link:
[ckecked element number in :nth-child css rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867858/ckecked-element-number-in-nth-child-css-rule?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

The answer is just what I'm looking for but I can't figure out how to set the first Tab as default when the page loads? In the above link it is said that: "you may call the page with the hash #section1". Can anyone perhaps show me how to do this in code? I have been trying for a long time but can't seem to make this work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The people that suggested "you may call the page with the hash #section1" refer to the URL: if your page is http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage simply navigate to http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage#content1 (content1 because is the id of the first section in the example you provided).

Personally I don't like this solution because it's not flexible and maintainable but nevertheless it works for your simple example.

I'd go for a js based solution: at the begin I'd show only the first section and on click I'd hide all and show only desired one.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/o8c3g773/) (HTML + CSS + JS with jQuery).

HTML:

The same you provided.

CSS:

```
section { display: none }
section:first-of-type { display: block; }
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('section').hide();
   $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

Of course you don't need jQuery to do this but it was faster to write for me :)
Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I can't seem to make my own file work the way your fiddle works. I tweaked my CSS file to be a duplicate of yours. Then I include the JS code in <script type="text/javascript"></script>. Is this wrong? I'm a complete noob at this so I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

In pure-CSS solution involving `:target`, you anyway need JS to go to URL with corresponding hash (e.g. `location.hash = 'content1'`).

It's generally more flexible to show all tabs by default (incl. when JS is disabled), and hide/show/switch tabs with JS.